# Error occurred when adding more property to class and running migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id {get; set}
}

public class NoteBook
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Student Student {get; set;}
}
```

I also specify the optional:option relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NoteBook>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.Student)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(config => config.MapKey("StudentId");
```

With the above configuration, I got the expected tables:

- Student: Id.
- NoteBook: Id, StudentId.

Now I want to add the property `StudentId` (of type nullable Guid) to the NoteBook class. When running add-migration, I got this error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> StudentId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property
>   name 'StudentId' is already defined.

As far as I understand, entity framework is trying to create a new column called `StudentId` to the table `NoteBook`. What should I do now? Thank you.

Comment: You can simply add `StudentId` to `NoteBook` class without Fluent API at all.

Comment: The Fluent API has been already there all the time. I didn't add it. I just want to add a new property to `StudentId ` to the class `NoteBook`. Without the Fluent API, the generated column name will be `Student_Id`, which I don't expect. @SlavaUtesinov

Comment: Without Fluent API and with explicitly specified property `StudentId` FK will be exactly `StudentId`, try it.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.